# Output Test results XUnit .net core when using IClassFixture

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, xunit.net

I used Nunit all the time and now moved to XUnit.

I use `ITestOutputHelper` successfully when I do not implement `IClassFixture`, e.g.:

```
public myClassTest(ITestOutputHelper outputHelper)
{
    this.outputHelper = outputHelper;
}
```

However when I implement `IClassFixture` I cannot find a way to inject `ITestOutputHelper`.

Sample where I cannot Implement ITestOutputHelper

```
public class MyIntegrationTests : IClassFixture<TestServerFixture<Startup>>
{
    public MyIntegrationTests (TestServerFixture<Startup> testServerFixture)
    {
        client = testServerFixture.Client;
    }
}
```

Am I missing the obvious?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should Just Work by doing:

```
public class MyIntegrationTests : IClassFixture<TestServerFixture<Startup>>
{
    public MyIntegrationTests (TestServerFixture<Startup> testServerFixture, ITestOutputHelper outputHelper)
    {
        client = testServerFixture.Client;
        this.outputHelper = outputHelper;
    }
}
```

as `ITestOutputHelper`, and all declared Class and Shared fixtures can get provided in this way.

What message are you being given in the Output window *(Ctrl-Alt-O)*'s *Tests* panel ?

Comment: silly me .that worked ,For some reasons I was getting an error doing what you suggested. Never mind .Thank you!! one last thing. none of these outputs are shown in the output window correct only in the test runner screen .Correct?

Comment: @developer9969 Yes, I believe the idea is that this output sink does not emit anywhere other than to the test runner host on the basis that parallel runs are interleaved and would hence make a mess. You could easily decorate it and/or make a fixture to wrap it and do a `Trace.WriteLine` I guess. When last I looked about 2y ago IIRC it was a VS bug that the output is not rendered in VS. (I tend to do logging to Seq for this sort of thing, though admittedly that does not solve the issue of correlating with a test case run)

Answer (score 0):

There's a *slightly* better solution nowadays, which is the use of the `IMessageSink` class instead of the `ITestOutputHelper` in the fixture's constructor. Posting the messages and seeing them is quite obscure, [here's the link to the docs](https://xunit.net/docs/capturing-output#output-in-extensions).

[Here's the example of the config file](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/565#issuecomment-926205098) in the related thread.

I use R#, and I couldn't find a way to see the output in its runner, but I can find it in the Outputs->Tests when using VS's default test runner.
I need this diagnostic functionality for CI/CD machine, so I can live with that.